# Long/complex INSERT and UPDATE query parser or visual editor/query builder

Tags: sql-server, tools, sql-server-tools

I have long `INSERT` queries that insert  values to table with over 50 columns. Is there any tool to parse this long query to key-value representation?

like:

`INSERT INTO sometable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)`

parse to:

```
col1: 1
col2: 2
col3: 3
```

So it would be easier to analyze.

Comment: Python should do it in a snap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is with the [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1). This can be used from a .NET application or PowerShell script. The assembly is available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom/14.0.3660.1) or, if you already have SQL Server tools installed, you can reference an existing assembly in the Program Files (x86) folder.

Below is a PowerShell example that uses the assembly installed by SSMS.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Extensions\Application\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"

$query = "INSERT INTO sometable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)"

# use the appropriate TSqlParser version for the scripts being parsed
$parser = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.TSql140Parser($true)
$parseErrors = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.ParseError]

$scriptReader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($query)

$fragment = $parser.Parse($scriptReader, [ref]$parseErrors)
if($parseErrors.Count -eq 0) {
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].InsertSpecification.Columns.Count; ++$i) {
        $columnName = $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].InsertSpecification.Columns[$i].MultiPartIdentifier[0].Value 
        $columnValue = $fragment.Batches[0].Statements[0].InsertSpecification.InsertSource.RowValues[0].ColumnValues[$i].Value
        Write-Host "$columnName`: $columnValue"
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "$($parseErrors.Count) parsing errors. First error: $($parseErrors[0].Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: A good solution but doesn't work with more complex value types like function calls and conversions and variable references.

Comment: I converted it to C# and modified a little bit by using `Sql150ScriptGenerator`. Thanks

Comment: requires more work but works https://pastebin.com/0RN9PssE

Comment: @Konrad, the code I provided was just an example for this particular use case but can be extended for other specialized needs.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not sufficiently address your problem, but when I'm faced with this situation, I paste the statement into [Poor SQL](http://poorsql.com/) and view the formatted results

Original:

`INSERT INTO sometable(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)`

Formatted:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (
    col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
    )
VALUES (
    1
    ,2
    ,3
    )
```

I then bring up Word and create a 2 column table.  I paste the columns from the formatted result into the first column of the Word table and paste the values from the formatted result into the second column of the Word table

[image]

Comment: Great simple method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any tool, but I structure the insert with each column on a row and I use SELECT instead of VALUES. I give an alias for each value which gives me a clue about what column is used in insert.
Example:

```
INSERT INTO sometable
(
   col1,
   col2,
   col3
)
SELECT
   col1 = 1,
   col2 = 2,
   col3 = 3
```

Pay attention that the alias in the select is just an alias ie if you write

```
SELECT
   col2 = 2,
   col1 = 1,
   col3 = 3
```

the value from col2 (2) will still go in the first field in the insert (col1).